# MSSQL UNION var types mismatch

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

Question asked before and I believe I did all necessary conversions, yet I'm getting error: `Error converting data type nvarchar to float`. The error message is referencing to `SnapperMusic_Winman` - View1

View1:

```
SELECT     Products.ProductId AS Product, Products.ProductDescription AS Description, CONVERT(datetime, PurchaseOrders.EffectiveDate) AS OrderDate, 
                      Suppliers.SupplierId AS SupplierAcc, Suppliers.SupplierName, CONVERT(datetime, Inventory.EffectiveDate) AS BookedDate, CONVERT(float, Inventory.Quantity) 
                      AS Quantity, CONVERT(float, Inventory.TotalValue) AS TotalValue, Locations.LocationId AS Location, PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrderId AS PONumber, 
                      GoodsReceipts.GoodsReceiptId AS GoodsReference
FROM         SnapperMusic_Winman.dbo.GoodsReceipts AS GoodsReceipts INNER JOIN
                      SnapperMusic_Winman.dbo.Inventory AS Inventory ON GoodsReceipts.GoodsReceipt = Inventory.GoodsReceipt INNER JOIN
                      SnapperMusic_Winman.dbo.Suppliers AS Suppliers ON GoodsReceipts.Supplier = Suppliers.Supplier INNER JOIN
                      SnapperMusic_Winman.dbo.Products AS Products ON Inventory.Product = Products.Product INNER JOIN
                      SnapperMusic_Winman.dbo.Locations AS Locations ON Inventory.Location = Locations.Location INNER JOIN
                      SnapperMusic_Winman.dbo.PurchaseOrderItems AS PurchaseOrderItems ON Inventory.PurchaseOrderItem = PurchaseOrderItems.PurchaseOrderItem INNER JOIN
                      SnapperMusic_Winman.dbo.PurchaseOrders AS PurchaseOrders ON PurchaseOrderItems.PurchaseOrder = PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrder
```

View2:

```
SELECT     GoodsReceipts.ItemCode AS Product, dbo.StockItem.Name AS Description, CONVERT(datetime, dbo.POPOrderReturn.DocumentDate) AS OrderDate, 
                      dbo.PLSupplierAccount.SupplierAccountNumber AS SupplierAcc, dbo.PLSupplierAccount.SupplierAccountName AS SupplierName, CONVERT(datetime, 
                      dbo.POPReceiptReturnLine.DateTimeCreated) AS BookedDate, CONVERT(float, dbo.POPReceiptReturnLine.ReceiptReturnQuantity) AS Quantity, CONVERT(float, 
                      GoodsReceipts.UnitBuyingPrice * dbo.POPReceiptReturnLine.ReceiptReturnQuantity) AS TotalValue, dbo.Warehouse.Name AS Location, 
                      dbo.POPOrderReturn.DocumentNo AS PONumber, dbo.POPInvoiceCreditLine.POPInvoiceCreditNo AS GoodsReference
FROM         dbo.POPOrderReturnLine AS GoodsReceipts INNER JOIN
                      dbo.POPReceiptReturnLine ON GoodsReceipts.POPOrderReturnLineID = dbo.POPReceiptReturnLine.POPOrderReturnLineID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.POPOrderReturn ON GoodsReceipts.POPOrderReturnID = dbo.POPOrderReturn.POPOrderReturnID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.PLSupplierAccount ON dbo.POPOrderReturn.SupplierID = dbo.PLSupplierAccount.PLSupplierAccountID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Warehouse ON dbo.POPOrderReturn.WarehouseID = dbo.Warehouse.WarehouseID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.POPInvoiceCreditLine ON GoodsReceipts.POPOrderReturnLineID = dbo.POPInvoiceCreditLine.POPOrderReturnLineID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.StockItem ON GoodsReceipts.ItemCode = dbo.StockItem.Code
```

Union:

```
SELECT     dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Winman.Product, dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Winman.Description, dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Winman.OrderDate, 
                      dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Winman.SupplierAcc, dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Winman.SupplierName, dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Winman.BookedDate, 
                      dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Winman.Quantity, dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Winman.Location, dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Winman.TotalValue, 
                      dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Winman.PONumber, dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Winman.GoodsReference
FROM         dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Winman
UNION
SELECT    dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Sage.Product, dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Sage.Description, dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Sage.OrderDate, 
                      dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Sage.SupplierAcc , dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Sage.SupplierName, 
                      dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Sage.BookedDate, dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Sage.Quantity, 
                      dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Sage.TotalValue, dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Sage.Location, 
                      dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Sage.PONumber, dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Sage.GoodsReference
FROM         dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Sage
```

Apart from converted fields all others are `VARCHAR`. 
Needless to say that individually they work fine..

Can anyone point out what am I missing please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `order` of columns in the `select` statements wrong at one point.

In `view1` it is

```
   dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Winman.Location,     
   dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Winman.TotalValue,
```

In `view2` it is

```
 dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Sage.TotalValue, 
 dbo.Elen_GoodsInReceived_Sage.Location,
```

Change this order to be appropriate.

Comment: GOSH!! that's why you need a pair of fresh eyes! yes that was exactly what was wrong.... 
Just to add - the the wrong order of columns appears in `UNION`